# Reading columns from a file into a struct

Tags: c, scanf

I have an assignment to read from a file a table similar to:

```
    MERCURY VENUS   EARTH   MARS    JUPITER SATURN  URANUS  NEPTUNE PLUTO
Mass(10^24kg)   0.33    4.87    5.97    0.642   1898    568 86.8    102 0.0146
Diameter(km)    4879    12104   12756   6792    142984  120536  51118   49528   2370
Density(kg/m^3) 5427    5243    5514    3933    1326    687 1271    1638    2095
Gravity(m/s^2)  3.7 8.9 9.8 3.7 23.1    9   8.7 11  0.7
Escape_Velocity(km/s)   4.3 10.4    11.2    5   59.5    35.5    21.3    23.5    1.3
Rotation_Period(hours)  1407.6  -5832.5 23.9    24.6    9.9 10.7    -17.2   16.1    -153.3
...
```

where there are 20 categories of values (mass, diameter, density...)
and 9 planets.

I'm trying to read in the data into a `struct planet` with the 20 components (mass, diameter, density...) and it compiles but I can't print any of the structure components in the output (like `p[2].A`) so it doesn't look like I'm even reading in the data from the file (and I definitely saved it in the right place). Because I'm trying to read columns into the `struct`, it's a bit messy...

```
typedef struct {char A[30]; char B[10]; char C[10]; float D; char E[10]; char F[10]; char G[10]; char H[10]; char I[10]; char J[10]; char K[10]; char L[10]; char M[10]; char N[10]; char O[10]; char P[10]; char Q[10]; char R[10]; char S[10]; char T[4]; char U[4];}planet;

int main(void) {
FILE * fp;
FILE * fs;
int i=0, j=0;
planet p[9];
char label[20][30];
char x[20][30];

fp=fopen("planets.txt", "r");
if (fp==NULL)printf("ERROR\n");

for(j=0; j<9; i++){                             //this for loop read the planet names
    fscanf(fp, "%s", p[i].A);
    }

for(i=0; i<20; i++){                            //this for loop counts the rows and reads the labels
    fscanf(fp, "%s", label[i]);                 //label[0] corresponds to .B values
    for(j=0; j<9; j++){                         //this for loop reads values across the rows and assigns them to the labels
        fscanf(fp, "%s", x[j]);
        if (i==0)strcpy(p[j].B, x[j]);
        else if (i==1) strcpy(p[j].C, x[j]);
        else if (i==2){
            p[j].D=atof(x[j]);
        }
        else if (i==3) strcpy(p[j].E, x[j]);
        else if (i==4) strcpy(p[j].F, x[j]);
        else if (i==5) strcpy(p[j].G, x[j]);
        else if (i==6) strcpy(p[j].H, x[j]);
        else if (i==7) strcpy(p[j].I, x[j]);
        else if (i==8) strcpy(p[j].J, x[j]);
        else if (i==9) strcpy(p[j].K, x[j]);
        else if (i==10) strcpy(p[j].L, x[j]);
        else if (i==11) strcpy(p[j].M, x[j]);
        else if (i==12) strcpy(p[j].N, x[j]);
        else if (i==13) strcpy(p[j].O, x[j]);
        else if (i==14) strcpy(p[j].P, x[j]);
        else if (i==15) strcpy(p[j].Q, x[j]);
        else if (i==16) strcpy(p[j].R, x[j]);
        else if (i==17) strcpy(p[j].S, x[j]);
        else if (i==18) strcpy(p[j].T, x[j]);
        else if (i==19) strcpy(p[j].U, x[j]);
    }
    i++;
}
```

...

Can anyone see a problem with this method?

Comment: Is the data really missing the tag `planet` or `name` from the first row?  Your layout of your structure is abominable; white space is cheap and should be used.  The names of the structure elements are opaque.  It's not clear why element `D` is a `float` when all the others are `char`.  You should have a `NUM_PLANETS` instead of 9 (interesting to see that Pluto has been reinstated as a planet).  I'm not clear how you're skipping commas.  Have you added printing?

Comment: sorry, the commas aren't actually in the table, i just typed it like that to separate things. element D (density) is a float because it is the only element that is being used as a value to sort the structs (i need to reprint the table but with the planets ordered by descending density). the rest of the elements don't matter, so i'm reading them as strings so i can reprint them in the new table.
i've written everything to sort and fprinft to another file, and i've also tried to just printf it straight back out but get nothing

Comment: and yes, its missing a label for the first row

Comment: Please show the data as it really is.  Indent it like you would code.  Have you printed out each field value as you read it?  Have you error checked each call to an input function?  We don't need all 20 rows; indeed, you would have a better MCVE ([MCVE]) with just 6 rows but all 9 columns plus label.

Comment: why don't you use `char x[30];` and then `x`  instead of `x[j]`  . You copy out each string after reading it, there's no need to hold a whole line in memory at once

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your immediate problem is this loop:

```
for (j = 0; j < 9; i++)
```

You're comparing `j` but incrementing `i`.  Use `j++` and change the body of the loop.  Or use `i` throughout.

```
    for (j = 0; j < 9; j++)
    {
        if (fscanf(fp, "%s", p[j].A) != 1)
        {
            fprintf(stderr, "Failed to scan a planet name\n");
            return 1;
        }
        printf("Planet name: [%s]\n", p[j].A);
    }
```

Your `for (i = 0; i < 20; i++)` loop has a problem too:

```
    for (i = 0; i < 20; i++)
    {
        printf("Line %d\n", i+2);
        if (fscanf(fp, "%s", label[i]) != 1)
        {
            fprintf(stderr, "Failed to read a label\n");
            return 1;
        }
        for (j = 0; j < 9; j++)                 // this for loop reads values across the rows and assigns them to the labels
        {
            if (fscanf(fp, "%s", x[j]) != 1)
            {
                fprintf(stderr, "Failed to read value for %s\n", p[j].A);
                return 1;
            }
            printf("Value: [%s] for %s\n", x[j], p[j].A);
            if (i == 0)
                strcpy(p[j].B, x[j]);
            …
        }
        i++;
    }
```

You have two increments to `i`.  Note the error checking that I added.

This is 'working' code for the 6-lines plus planet names data set you have in the question.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>

typedef struct
{
    char A[30];
    char B[10];
    char C[10];
    float D;
    char E[10];
    char F[10];
    char G[10];
    char H[10];
    char I[10];
    char J[10];
    char K[10];
    char L[10];
    char M[10];
    char N[10];
    char O[10];
    char P[10];
    char Q[10];
    char R[10];
    char S[10];
    char T[4];
    char U[4];
} planet;

int main(void)
{
    FILE *fp;
    int i = 0, j = 0;
    planet p[9];
    char label[20][30];
    char x[20][30];
    const char filename[] = "planets.txt";

    fp = fopen(filename, "r");
    if (fp == NULL)
    {
        fprintf(stderr, "Failed to open file %s\n", filename);
        return 1;
    }

    for (j = 0; j < 9; j++)                     // this for loop read the planet names
    {
        if (fscanf(fp, "%s", p[j].A) != 1)
        {
            fprintf(stderr, "Failed to scan a planet name\n");
            return 1;
        }
        printf("Planet name: [%s]\n", p[j].A);
    }

    for (i = 0; i < 6; i++)                    // this for loop counts the rows and reads the labels
    {
        printf("Line %d\n", i+2);
        if (fscanf(fp, "%s", label[i]) != 1)
        {
            fprintf(stderr, "Failed to read a label\n");
            return 1;
        }
        printf("Label: [%s]\n", label[i]);
        for (j = 0; j < 9; j++)                 // this for loop reads values across the rows and assigns them to the labels
        {
            if (fscanf(fp, "%s", x[j]) != 1)
            {
                fprintf(stderr, "Failed to read value for %s\n", p[j].A);
                return 1;
            }
            printf("Value: [%s] for %s\n", x[j], p[j].A);
            if (i == 0)
                strcpy(p[j].B, x[j]);
            else if (i == 1)
                strcpy(p[j].C, x[j]);
            else if (i == 2)
                p[j].D = atof(x[j]);
            else if (i == 3)
                strcpy(p[j].E, x[j]);
            else if (i == 4)
                strcpy(p[j].F, x[j]);
            else if (i == 5)
                strcpy(p[j].G, x[j]);
            else if (i == 6)
                strcpy(p[j].H, x[j]);
            else if (i == 7)
                strcpy(p[j].I, x[j]);
            else if (i == 8)
                strcpy(p[j].J, x[j]);
            else if (i == 9)
                strcpy(p[j].K, x[j]);
            else if (i == 10)
                strcpy(p[j].L, x[j]);
            else if (i == 11)
                strcpy(p[j].M, x[j]);
            else if (i == 12)
                strcpy(p[j].N, x[j]);
            else if (i == 13)
                strcpy(p[j].O, x[j]);
            else if (i == 14)
                strcpy(p[j].P, x[j]);
            else if (i == 15)
                strcpy(p[j].Q, x[j]);
            else if (i == 16)
                strcpy(p[j].R, x[j]);
            else if (i == 17)
                strcpy(p[j].S, x[j]);
            else if (i == 18)
                strcpy(p[j].T, x[j]);
            else if (i == 19)
                strcpy(p[j].U, x[j]);
        }
    }

}
```

The sample output (from echoing the inputs):

```
Planet name: [MERCURY]
Planet name: [VENUS]
Planet name: [EARTH]
Planet name: [MARS]
Planet name: [JUPITER]
Planet name: [SATURN]
Planet name: [URANUS]
Planet name: [NEPTUNE]
Planet name: [PLUTO]
Line 2
Label: [Mass(10^24kg)]
Value: [0.33] for MERCURY
Value: [4.87] for VENUS
Value: [5.97] for EARTH
Value: [0.642] for MARS
Value: [1898] for JUPITER
Value: [568] for SATURN
Value: [86.8] for URANUS
Value: [102] for NEPTUNE
Value: [0.0146] for PLUTO
Line 3
Label: [Diameter(km)]
Value: [4879] for MERCURY
Value: [12104] for VENUS
Value: [12756] for EARTH
Value: [6792] for MARS
Value: [142984] for JUPITER
Value: [120536] for SATURN
Value: [51118] for URANUS
Value: [49528] for NEPTUNE
Value: [2370] for PLUTO
Line 4
Label: [Density(kg/m^3)]
Value: [5427] for MERCURY
Value: [5243] for VENUS
Value: [5514] for EARTH
Value: [3933] for MARS
Value: [1326] for JUPITER
Value: [687] for SATURN
Value: [1271] for URANUS
Value: [1638] for NEPTUNE
Value: [2095] for PLUTO
Line 5
Label: [Gravity(m/s^2)]
Value: [3.7] for MERCURY
Value: [8.9] for VENUS
Value: [9.8] for EARTH
Value: [3.7] for MARS
Value: [23.1] for JUPITER
Value: [9] for SATURN
Value: [8.7] for URANUS
Value: [11] for NEPTUNE
Value: [0.7] for PLUTO
Line 6
Label: [Escape_Velocity(km/s)]
Value: [4.3] for MERCURY
Value: [10.4] for VENUS
Value: [11.2] for EARTH
Value: [5] for MARS
Value: [59.5] for JUPITER
Value: [35.5] for SATURN
Value: [21.3] for URANUS
Value: [23.5] for NEPTUNE
Value: [1.3] for PLUTO
Line 7
Label: [Rotation_Period(hours)]
Value: [1407.6] for MERCURY
Value: [-5832.5] for VENUS
Value: [23.9] for EARTH
Value: [24.6] for MARS
Value: [9.9] for JUPITER
Value: [10.7] for SATURN
Value: [-17.2] for URANUS
Value: [16.1] for NEPTUNE
Value: [-153.3] for PLUTO
```

It was easy to spot the mal-formed loop controls when the program claimed everything was a planet name.